# When should I resign while the company is re-organizing?

Tags: resignation, europe

In the last couple of weeks, I've been in contact with another company for a great position.
Although this other company offered me the position some days ago already, only today I've received the offer signed on their side.
I'm planning to sign since it is simply a great opportunity (without even considering the things that I don't like at my current company), and of course I need to resign at my current company.

The issue is that tomorrow afternoon my current company will announce a re-organization (nothing would change for my position, but I'm part of it). I would have resigned earlier, but only today I've received the signed offer. Therefore, I'm wondering if I should resign tomorrow morning or on Monday of next week.
On one hand, resigning before the re-organization announcement would be more "fair" to the company, but I also realize that it could backfire as I would give the company only few hours to deal with my resignation (definitely not enough) that could be seen as "yeah, thanks, too late".
Resigning on Monday would also be "too late", but maybe it would be a bit more "fair"?

My resignation will come as a surprise (although I pointed out quite some issues in the last 1-2 months), and I would like to leave the company with no hard feelings.

Note: I would start the new job in February 2022.

EDIT: company has ~250 employees. The re-organization is about one department "only" (around 50 people more or less). I am managing a small (growing in size) team.

Comment: What exactly could backfire?  Are you expecting some counter-offer that you would consider?

Comment: @sf02 backfire means parting ways in bad terms. If they counter the offer, I wouldn't accept it for different reasons.

Comment: @HBv6 if you resign today, you still have to serve your notice period, which is usually 2 weeks. What is the notice period you have or agreed in your contract? Such time is precisely for handling things like this, so they don't have hours or a single day to sort this out.

Comment: @DarkCygnus This is in Europe. I have up to the last day of this month to resign such that I can start in February.

Comment: There's no such thing as fair. They wouldn't extend you the same courtesy. What they do regarding your resignation is their concern, not yours. Your employment is a business transaction. Your only obligation is to perform the work for which they pay you and to be professional in your dealings. Stop having moral quandaries about this.

Comment: Their reorganization is their problem. Fulfill your legal and contractual obligations to the letter, give advanced notice as required, pack your bags and leave. Your old employer is already your past.

Comment: Why would their reorganization be this significantly impacted based on the _announcement_ date? One would assume that they've been planning this reorganization for longer, no?

Comment: Makes little difference. You could mention that you had already decided prior to the reorg announcement, so they don't feel like you owe them the expectation of a courtesy delay. Alternatively, if you are resigning because of a specific person but want to be polite, say nothing about the timing, and the reorg wil be blamed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations to the signed offer you have received today!

> The issue is that tomorrow afternoon my current company will announce a re-organization (nothing would change for my position, but I'm part of it). I would have resigned earlier, but only today I've received the signed offer. Therefore, I'm wondering if I should resign tomorrow morning or on Monday of next week.

Keeping in mind that your resignation will surprise them a bit (thou that shouldn't be your concern) - here are my ​thoughts:

It doesn't really matter since:

- It will be a surprise for your current employer in both cases (but again, you don't owe them anything and it's their responsibility to be prepared for people departing - especially in a company with ~250 employees).
- Both scenarios would have the same impact on a possible reference from your current employer (which you might not need since you have a signed offer already).
- Wouldn't change anything with embarking on the new gig due to the start-date in February.
- Wouldn't change much in terms of your notice period (you will be out the door just a couple of days more or less).

Personally, I think it would be best for you to evaluate when to resign since you know your company, superiors, their views and the duties when serving your notice period.

Again, you shouldn't have any hard feelings about this - that's just business. You take care of yourself and companies in general look out what's in the best interest for them.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you have done the right thing by waiting until you have an official offer from the new company before resigning.  That's important!

Now all you need to do is to turn in your resignation at your earliest convenience.  I don't see why events going on at your present company in any way affect the timing of your resignation.  Do it sooner rather than later which will allow them the most time to backfill the position.

Answer (score 2):

If the company is large, then the resignation of one person just before the announcement wouldn't change anything. Your manager once named would start the process of filing the position. The only issue would be if the manager was changing, the timing of the interviews might be delayed to allow the new people to get in place.

Now if the company is small then your announcement does make a difference. They may want to reposition people based on your leaving.

In reality they have to know that any re-organization will result in people leaving, or at least grumbling. They should be prepared for this situation.

Pick the date to inform your current company that makes the most sense for you, and your new employer. Personally I wouldn't even sign the offer letter until the reorganization announcement is made, just in case the reorganization makes me want to stay.

Comment: I already know what is going to happen, and I am actually one of the few people who would benefit from the re-organization. I also know that other people are going to leave because of the re-org. I definitely understand your point, but the reason for leaving is simply that I've received a way better opportunity.